# String errors due to serial data

Tags: python

I am fairly new with python and currently only using it to try and plot data from my microcontroller.

```
import serial
import numpy
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from drawnow import *

port = serial.Serial('com4',9600)

while True:
   while (port.inWaiting()==0):
        pass
   sstring = port.readline()
   dataArray = sstring.split(',')

   Pterm = float(dataArray[0])
   Iterm = float(dataArray[1])
   Dterm = float(dataArray[2])
   Error = float(dataArray[3])

   print Pterm
   print Iterm
   print Dterm
   print Error
   print
```

Now, sometime I receive the data with no problem ;

[image: Data that was successfully received]

But other times I get messages like;

- Unrecognized character 0 in format string
- could not convert string to float
- 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xa9 in position 35: ordinal not in range(128)

The strings I transmit over serial from my microcontroller always look like the above figure but with different magnitudes.

Can I adjust my code to solve or maybe even ignore these errors in a manner that the script stil keeps on running?

Comment: You should investigate what you are *actually* receiving from the microcontroller. Simply doing `print sstring` seems like a good start.

Comment: in general, I've found that slamming a serial port with as-fast-as-possible reads will sometimes generate garbage data. You just need to handle each of these cases.

Comment: [Handle the exception(s)](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/errors.html#handling-exceptions) and in the except suite print out the relevant  data.

Answer (score 0):

it seems that when I added a decode method to my code it started working better.

I changed `sstring = port.readline()`

to `sstring = port.readline().decode('ascii').strip()`

Thank you for the assistance and I will be sure to include exception handling.